# File inputs&outputs

Tags: c#, c, file, batch-file

Hey everyone.
I have an exe file that runs a console program that was programmed in C.

during the run of the program the user is asked to enter numbers (using the scanf function).
and the output is being printed to the screen by printf.

The thing is this. I want to make my own txt file with inputs and I want the program to use those inputs.
I also want that the output will be printed to a different txt file - and not in the command window (or in addition to the command windows - I don't care if it's both).

how can I do that, in c#? or can I create a *.bat file that will do that? - that would be best.

Another question:
Is there a way to create a *.bat file that will check if two txt files are the same?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a lot of different questions.

Do you want to reimplement the whole thing using a batch script? That will be, in short, nightmarish since batch is light on features, and it depends on how you process input to obtain your output.

You can do this in C# (Or C, since you tagged it that?). You can open your text file, and open a second file, and process that file and write to the second file.

Comment: Try using named pipes : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the program was written to read from `stdin` (standard input) and write to `stdout` (standard output), you should be able to use the following command line:

```
program.exe < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: I posted this about a minute later, but will delete - I'd add that if the C console program does not use `stdin` and `stdout` then you can not do this without modifying it, or setting up a virtual execution environment and emulating keystrokes (which is complicated way beyond a stackoverflow question).

Comment: Thanks, that works, but if I put in the input file, less then the input amount that the program needs it enters an infinit loop.. 
can I stop it?

Comment: and what about to check if two files are the same?

Thanks again

Comment: "Thanks, that works, but if I put in the input file, less then the input amount that the program needs it enters an infinit loop.. can I stop it?" ------ No. The program has to be augmented to handle the "not enough input" condition.